# Can a division algebra have degree divisible by its characteristic?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, division-algebras, positive-characteristic

I apologize in advance if this is easy, but I've tried Googling, and had no luck.

I'm currently working on a proof, and I realized in the course of writing that this proof will break if out there in the world there exists a division algebra $D$ with the following properties:

1. The characteristic of $D$ (as a normal ring) is $p$.
2. The degree of $D$ (the square root of its dimension over its center) is divisible by $p$.

I would really appreciate if anyone knows an example, or a proof that there are none.  I could easily add hypotheses to rule out this case, but that would make things a bit messier, so I don't want to do that unless it's really necessary.  Unfortunately, I know zippo about division algebras in characteristic p, other than that every finite one is actually just a field.

**EDIT**: Thanks for the references.  Doing a little reading based on Mikhail's suggestion, I found a result which is good enough for my purposes:  no such division algebra exists whose center is a perfect field, which was proven in 1934 by the remarkably named [Abraham Adrian Albert](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1934-036-02/S0002-9947-1934-1501750-X/home.html).    Those wanting more details on his life can read this [detailed and impressive obituary](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1974-80-06/S0002-9904-1974-13622-0/S0002-9904-1974-13622-0.pdf) by Jacobson.  The best detail is that his Ukrainian father decided to ditch his last name (which is now unknown!) in Victorian England, and adopt the prince consort's name instead.

Comment: I believe that there exists such a division algebra. Probably, an example was constructed in Hochschild, G.
Simple algebras with purely inseparable splitting fields of exponent 1. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 79, (1955). 477–489.

Comment: Also, look at: Aljadeff, Eli(IL-TECH); Sonn, Jack(IL-TECH)
Relative Brauer groups and m-torsion. (English summary) 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 130 (2002), no. 5, 1333–1337. A related result that seems to be true: for a local field of characteristic $p$ the $p$-torsion of the Brauer group is non-zero (and is ind-cyclic).

Comment: http://msp.org/pjm/1997/181-3/pjm-v181-n3-p07-s.pdf mentions this for perfect center via Albert in Thm 2.5 using the language of Brauer groups.

Comment: The most basic noncommutative division rings are non-split quaternion algebras, which are of dimension 4 over their centers, and there are many non-split quaternion algebras in characteristic 2. A construction over the simplest nonperfect field of characteristic 2, $\mathbf F_2(t)$, is in exercise 11 of http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/ross2004/quatset4.pdf.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are counterexamples for each $p$. The easiest maybe is the following: Let $F$ be the field of order $p^p$, and $\sigma$ be an automorphism of $F$ of order $p$. Let $D=F((t))$ be the set of Laurent series of the form $\sum a_it^i$ with the usual addition. Define multiplication by $ta=a^\sigma t$. Then $D$ is a division algebra with center $Z=\mathbb F_p((t^p))$, so $[F:Z]=p^2$.